How to authenticate the services/apps( not users) calling an azure app service APIs
I have an azure app service. I am authenticating the users using their login through Azure active directory and a dedicated security group. I would like to know how I can authenticate other applications/services  calling my azure app service API.
Constraints:

My application is Asp.Net framework and not .net core
I cant use any secrets/cert anywhere
I would like to make no code change in my application - i.e. I am looking for a built in solution with minimal changes.
I want to allow only specific services access and others should not have access to my app service APIs

My app has its own application registration and it is also listed as an enterprise application.

I created a sample ASP .NET Framework application and successfully authenticated applications/services calling Azure App Service API.
Thanks to @medium.com, I've referred this doc and created the application.

Enable Azure App Service Authentication
Go to your app service -> Authentication -> add identity provider ->





Make sure you give correct API permissions in your App registrations.
This will provide the necessary authorization permissions to call the App API



Also enable CORS in your Azure App Service.

By following the doc and configuring all the necessary things now I can successfully access the API without making any changes to Code.


After Accepting you can view your application and also your required API's.



Thank you for the detailed response but this is for logging users in. I am looking for the services authentication where there is no browser and no user to log in

Can you please refer the doc once.
